# Why does it take so much time to realease/clear 100'000 objects in Excel-VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Main goal: I'm trying to store and manipulate "OVER 90000!" products in memory from a csv file (one line, one product).

For every product I create an object. That object has multiple String and integer fields:

```
Option Explicit

Private m_name As String
Private m_price As Integer
Private m_description As String
Private m_amount As Integer


Property Get name() As String
    name = m_name
End Property
Property Let name(value As String)
    m_name = value
End Property

Property Get price() As Integer
    price = m_price
End Property
Property Let price(value As Integer)
    m_price = value
End Property

Property Get description() As String
    description = m_description
End Property
Property Let description(value As String)
    m_description = value
End Property

Property Get amount() As Integer
    amount = m_amount
End Property
Property Let amount(value As Integer)
    m_amount = value
End Property
```

Problem: It is relatively fast to creat these object, but it takes a long time to clear/realease them, either with `set = nothing` or just at the end of the sub. Here's a testcode snippet, which counts the time used for precessing:

```
Option Explicit

'64 bit Version with "PtrSafe"
Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32.dll" () As Long

Sub TestSub()

    Dim t As Long
    t = GetTickCount
    'Start test code.

    TestFunction

    'End test code.
    Debug.Print GetTickCount - t, , "To delete"

End Sub




Sub TestFunction()

    Dim t As Long
    t = GetTickCount
    'Start test code.

    Dim testArray(99999) As TestProduct
    Dim i As Long
    Dim product As TestProduct

    For i = 0 To 99999
        Set testArray(i) = New TestProduct
    Next

    'End test code.
    Debug.Print GetTickCount - t, , "To create"

End Sub
```

Output (milliseconds):

```
235                        To create
7250                       To delete
```

As you can see, it takes almost 8 seconds to free up the memory at the end of the function/sub. I get the same result when I use this code `Redim testArray(0)` to clear the array.

Is there a better way to store this information in memory? Maybe with arrays or ADODB.recordsets?
I am using a ADODB.Stream to read the UTF-8 coded csv file line by line and store the information in objects.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why is the 7 seconds a problem?

Comment: I don't get it. If I do the same in python, it takes 0 seconds. The problem starts with 1 million products, if there are more variables in the class, it takes even more time. This is an example. 100'000 Products take 30+ second in my case to be deleted.

Comment: Normally, releasing variables does not need any time...is Vba setting all variables to 0 before deleting them or something like that?

Comment: SO Again.  Why is the time delay in deleting variables causing you a problem?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but in testing your code these are the results that I get:   281 -->  To create ;  2094 --> To delete .

Comment: The Problem is that I need to import multiple csv files with 100k+ products and merge them together. The code at the moment needs 2min to delete every product stored as  an object. The whole process needs 5min. The question was if it is possible to speed up this part. As an example: an ADODB object with 120k Products (lines) needs 0.2 seconds to be deleted ``Set rs = Nothing``. So where's the difference in deleting/clearing these objects?

Comment: If your objects have no methods, only fields, then it might be better/faster to use a Type/struct instead of a custom object

Comment: Tested - *much* faster with a struct, so if performance is key then that would be the way to go.

Comment: ...and a 2D array would also be fast.

Comment: @TimWilliams Perfect! Thanks a lot this, saved me a headache. It frees up the memory instantly and I don't need methods inside. Wonderful! Just happy.